# Add 1 Substract 1 onclick

Tags: javascript, addition

I am trying to create a form.

The objective is to have:

1. 28 players in total (ID=totalplayer)
2. shared in 4 groups of 7 players. (group = 4 AND position=7)
3. send the form.
4. When onclick right arrow add +1 to ID and position.
5. When position = 7 add +1 to group.

**My problem is when i get to position 7, group doesn't add +1.**

thank you,

```js
 /*
 function changeImageUp() will
 
 Add +1 to ID IdNum until hit 28 come back to 1.
 Add +1 to ID Postcounter hit 7 come back to 1.
 Add +1 to ID Groupcounter each time ID Postcounter hit 7.
 When ID Groupcounter hit 4 come back to 1.
 */
 function changeImageUp()
 { 

   positionID = document.getElementById("IdNum").getAttribute("name");
   
   
   if(positionID == 28)
   {
    positionID = 0;
   }
   

   var newPosition = parseInt(positionID) + 1;
   

   document.getElementById("IdNum").setAttribute("name", newPosition);
   

   document.getElementById("IdNum").innerHTML = "<input type= 'checkbox' name='ID' value='" + newPosition + "'checked> " + newPosition;
   
   

   positionSpot = document.getElementById("Poscounter").getAttribute("name");
   

   if(positionSpot == 7)
   {
    positionSpot = 0;
   }
   

   var newPositionSpot = parseInt(positionSpot) + 1;
   

   document.getElementById("Poscounter").setAttribute("name", newPositionSpot);
   

   document.getElementById("Poscounter").innerHTML = "<input type= 'checkbox' name='Position' value='" + newPositionSpot + "'checked> " + newPositionSpot;
   
   

   GroupSpot = document.getElementById("Groupcounter").getAttribute("name");
   if(GroupSpot == 4)
   {
    GroupSpot = 0;
   }
   
   
   if(positionID < 7)
   {
    GroupSpot = 1;
    document.getElementById("Groupcounter").innerHTML = "<input type= 'checkbox' name='Position' value='" + GroupSpot + "'checked> " + GroupSpot;
   }
   else if(positionID > 6)
   {
    GroupSpot = 2;
    document.getElementById("Groupcounter").innerHTML = "<input type= 'checkbox' name='Position' value='" + GroupSpot + "'checked> " + GroupSpot;
   }
   else
   {
    GroupSpot = 3;
    document.getElementById("Groupcounter").innerHTML = "<input type= 'checkbox' name='Position' value='" + GroupSpot + "'checked> " + GroupSpot;
   }

   
 }
 
 


  function changeImageDown()
 { 
   positionID = document.getElementById("IdNum").getAttribute("name");
   if(positionID <= 1)
   {
    positionID = 29;
   }
   var newPositionID = parseInt(positionID) - 1;
   
   document.getElementById("IdNum").setAttribute("name", newPositionID);
   document.getElementById("IdNum").innerHTML = newPositionID;
   
   positionSpot = document.getElementById("Poscounter").getAttribute("name");
  
   if(positionSpot <= 1)
   {
    positionSpot = 8;
    if(GroupSpot == 1)
    {
    GroupSpot = 5;
    }
    var newGroupSpot = parseInt(GroupSpot) - 1;
    document.getElementById("Groupcounter").setAttribute("name", newGroupSpot);
    document.getElementById("Groupcounter").innerHTML = newGroupSpot;
   }
   var newPositionSpot = parseInt(positionSpot) - 1;
   document.getElementById("Poscounter").setAttribute("name", newPositionSpot);
   document.getElementById("Poscounter").innerHTML = newPositionSpot;
   
   
   GroupSpot = document.getElementById("Groupcounter").getAttribute("name");
 }
```

```html
<!-- 
 Images of arrows pointing Right and left 
 arrow right: Onclick function changeImageUp() +1 to each DIV ID 
 arrow left: Onclick function changeImageDown()  -1 to each DIV ID 
-->
<div id="right" value="right" onclick="changeImageUp();"><image src="images/GroupArrow/right.png" /></div>
<div id="left" value="left" onclick="changeImageDown();"><image src="images/GroupArrow/left.png" /></div>

<!--
 Group name is set to 0 
 Position name is set to 0 
 ID name is set to 0 
-->
Group:<div id="Groupcounter" name="0"></div>
Position:<div id="Poscounter" name ="0"></div>
ID: <div id="IdNum" name="0"></div>
```

Comment: `<!-- newPosition ADD +1 to positionID -->` are not valid comments in javascript, those are `html` comments surely this is generating an error in your console. All of your comments should be like `// newPosition ADD +1 to positionID`  or like `/* newPosition ADD +1 to positionID */`

Comment: Additionally, this code could be simplified significantly by using jQuery which at first appears to be acceptable since you included the `jQuery` tag when asking your question. But, then in your question you state **"I am looking help to solve the code and not to upgrade it unless it is necessary to make it work."** Which indicates to me that using jQuery is not acceptable. You should probably remove the jQuery tag or make it clear that answers using it are acceptable. No one is going to rewrite just the problem part with jQuery, we'd re-write the whole thing to be simpler :)

Comment: it wasnt working before adding the comments, i just added the comment to make people understand my goal. And sorry i will change the tag

Comment: Sorry just fixed the code. it wasnt working before adding the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to roll numbers (set to zero if at a limit) you should use the modulo operation `%` instead (actually just the remainder of a division in JavaScript), so

```
positionID = positionID % 28;
```

,

```
positionSpot = positionSpot % 7;
```

and

```
GroupSpot = GroupSpot % 4;
```

According to your table

```
ID: 1-7 Group = 1
ID: 8-14 Group = 2
ID: 15-21 Group = 3
ID: 21-28 Group = 4
```

Starting at zero as of your code

```
ID: 0-6 Group = 0
ID: 7-13 Group = 1
ID: 14-19 Group = 2
ID: 20-27 Group = 3
```

The number of `Group` is the result of the division of `ID` by 7, so the value of `Group` can be computed from the value of `ID` directly by `GroupSpot = Math.floor(positionID / 7)` (if zero based).

BTW: it should not make a difference if you add one or subtract one as long as the sign stays the same, so you should be able to do it all in one function.

**EDIT:** added some example code

```
function changeImage(down) {

  positionID = parseInt(document.getElementById("IdNum").getAttribute("name"));
      if(down){
        positionID--;
      } else {
        positionID++;
      }
      if(positionID < 0){
        positionID = positionID + 28;
      }
      positionID = positionID % 28;   

  document.getElementById("IdNum").setAttribute("name", positionID);
  document.getElementById("IdNum").innerHTML =
    "<input type= 'checkbox' name='ID' value='" + positionID + "'checked> " +
    positionID;

  positionSpot = parseInt(document.getElementById("Poscounter").getAttribute("name"));
      if(down){
        positionSpot--;
      } else {
        positionSpot++;
      }
      if(positionSpot < 0){
         positionSpot =  positionSpot + 28;
      }
  positionSpot = positionSpot % 7;

  document.getElementById("Poscounter").setAttribute("name", positionSpot);
  document.getElementById("Poscounter").innerHTML =
    "<input type= 'checkbox' name='Position' value='" + positionSpot +
    "'checked> " + positionSpot;

  GroupSpot = parseInt(document.getElementById("Groupcounter").getAttribute("name"));
      // not necessary, because we do it directly
  // GroupSpot = GroupSpot % 4;

      GroupSpot = Math.floor(positionID / 7);

      document.getElementById("Groupcounter").innerHTML =
    "<input type= 'checkbox' name='Position' value='" +  GroupSpot +
    "'checked> " +  GroupSpot;
}
```

I don't know what you want to do if it rolls over all-zero to the left, so adjust to your needs.

Comment: What about all of the `<!-- blah blah blah -->` html comments that are preventing the code from even running?

Comment: just fixed the code, sorry. you were right the comments messed up everything. but still blocked on my orginal problem